# Javascript opener returns null when working on local (securityerror)

Tags: javascript

I have read many issues about that using `.opener` throws a security error due to the `null` result on Chrome:

> securityerror blocked a frame with origin null from accessing a
>   cross-origin frame

I am having this error working on local, so no cross origin issue must be happening here, I think.

I am using `.opener` to access to an array (`arrayName` in this case) placed on the current window's parent (opener):

```
opener.arrayName.push(newElement);
```

Why am I having the security error when working on local? How can I then stablish a data flow with the window's parent?

Thank you.

Comment: Could we get some more relevant code? Also, if you're using a popup window, and trying to access a variable from the popup's parent, you can't via `opener.variable` as the variable isn't global. You could do `window.arrayName = [1,2,3];` and then access it by `opener.arrayName.push(newElement);`.

Comment: Hi, the variable I am trying to access is global on the parent: I mean it is declared globally only on its parent.